# vc.net: cannot set double variable's value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, double

Developing environment: Visual studio 2005
language: c++

After running this line:

```
g_Frm->streamValue[0].dayAvgValue[0] = 1
```

I've already set `g_Frm->streamValue[0].dayAvgValue[0] = 1;`
(`g_Frm->streamValue[0].dayAvgValue[0] is type of double`)

But in the watch window, it still be displayed as -6.2774...e+066 as the variable is initialized.

Need help!

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

- Check that the variables in the construct you are referencing are defined.

i.e. Is g_Frm valid?  Is g_Frm->streamValue a valid array?  Is g_Frm->streamValue[0] valid array and index value?  Is g_Frm->streamValue[0]->dayAvgValue valid array?

If any of the variables in the chain of the variable you're trying to get to aren't initialized, you're going to get some undefined behavior.  Be sure you've allocated the memory and for valid index values (in general, in the case of the 0th element, you're likely good as long as there are elements there at all).

- If everything else is valid, check to see if you have a warning about implicit type conversion.  A 32 or 64 bit integer value of "1" is a substantially different value than a float/double value of "1.0".  Meaning in int world, your LSB (Least Significant Bit) is 1, but in float world, it represents an extremely small fractional value.

Comment: Thanks, Maximus. I have checked the variables, all are valid. Even I set the varialbe to 0 or 0.0. It still keeps being watched as -6.2774...e+066

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the relevant data structures?  I might be able to help more if I can see the whole picture :-).

Comment: Below is the declaration:                                       struct stream  
 {
     CString endpoint_name;//
  int date[31];
  CString ipAddress;
  double dayAvgValue[31];//
  
 }streamValue[MAXSTREAMNUM],streamValue_maxlatency[MAXSTREAMNUM],streamValue_avglatency[MAXSTREAMNUM],streamValue_jitter[MAXSTREAMNUM],streamValue_packetlost[MAXSTREAMNUM];//

Comment: By the way. Setting the variable's value is performed in a thread.

Comment: these code is running in a thread. After I moving the streamValue to a global variable, the issue is fixed. It's in a MainFrame variable before.

Comment: Sorry I was away today, or I would have answered sooner.  It sounds like the variable was getting set in thread local storage (TLS) and your debugger was running in a different (the parent) thread and looking at it's TLS instance of the variable.  Threading code and be very complex to debug, but sometimes the headache is worth it :-).